# "invalid_grant" error from DocuSign token api from an Angular SPA

Tags: c#, docusignapi, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using the below code to get access token and refresh token from docusign. 
But I'm always getting the invalid-grant error. I'm pasting the code below.

```
    [HttpGet("GetDocToken")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getToken(string docCode)
    {
        var x = docCode.Length;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var authCode=Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ced8998a-4387-4f30-9ab7-51c0d1af49bf:d7c3ccd4-22fa-4f18-a540-ddf11d8b2c9f"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authCode);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", docCode),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:4200/auth")
        });

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token", requestContent);
        string resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return Ok(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
```

Comment: What are you using to submit ?

Comment: "What are you using to submit ?" little confusing on this comment. I didnt understand the question

Comment: What I'm trying to say is what kind of UI technology you are using to submit the data the server ? Jquery ? Angular ? React ?

Comment: actually I'm using angular for my front end. From there I'm calling my web api. In that web api I'm calling the docusign api for token. Above I pasted is c# code

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that you have received the authentication code back from the DocuSign identity system and are trying to exchange it for an access token.

A couple of issues:

The [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant#step-2-obtain-the-access-token) incorrectly indicates that the redirect_uri should be included in the request. The Example Request in the docs does correctly show that the request should only include the `grant_type` and `code` parameters.

> Note: While the [OAuth standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), section 4.1 (d) does indicate that the redirect_url should be included, DocuSign usually does not include it.

My guess is that DocuSign will ignore the redirect_uri parameter, but you might want to try leaving it out.

**Another issue is timing**: The authorization code you receive back from DocuSign is only good for a minute or so. If you're not immediately using the authorization code (your code's `docCode`) then you'll get the Invalid Grant error.

### Known good example software

I suggest that you also check out the [known-good code example for C#](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core). You can use a protocol peeker to see exactly what it is doing during the authentication.

### Use a library

I also suggest that you look for an OAuth Authorization Code client library that you can use instead of rolling your own.

For example, are you setting and checking the state value? It's important to do that to stop CSRF attacks. See this [article](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state).

## Added

It is also not clear to me that you are using the right value as the `authorization code`.

I believe the flow should be:

1. User presses "Authenticate with DocuSign" in the Angular app.
2. User's browser does a GET to the DocuSign authentication server. At this point, the browser is no longer running the Angular app.
3. User's browser and DocuSign Authentication server exchange HTML back and forth as the user authenticates with DocuSign.
4. The user completes the authentication process with DocuSign.
5. DocuSign sends a REDIRECT response to the browser, telling the browser to do a GET on the redirect url. The redirect (and the GET) include query parameters for `code` and `state`
6. Your SERVER (not the Angular app), receives the GET request.
7. Your server should:

   1. Extract the `code` and `state` query parameters
   2. Verify that `state` is the same as was sent in step 2.
   3. Makes the POST request to DocuSign to exchange the authorization code for an access token.
   4. RESPONDS to the browser with the Angular program.
8. The Angular program is now once again running on the browser.

#### Use Implicit Grant

Your other option is to use Implicit Grant. That way you don't need a server component. With Implicit Grant, your Angular program handles the flow.